# How to use ?: operator

Tags: c#, string, conditional-operator

How would I convert the following code to use the ?: operator.. Is it Possible?

```
tbtotalamount.Text = string.Format("{0:n2}", dtl.Compute("sum(NetPay)", ""));
if (tbtotalamount.Text.Length == 0)
{
    tbtotalamount.Text = "0";
}
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The quoted code wouldn't benefit from using the `? :` operator, which is called the [*conditional operator*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) (sometimes called "the ternary operator" although technically, it's only **a** ternary operator — e.g., an operator that has three operands).

Typically the conditional operator is handy for when you have a variable and want to assign one of two values to it on the basis of a condition. So code in this form:

```
if (someCondition) {
    a = "one value";
}
else {
    a = "a different value";
}
```

can be rewritten

```
a = someCondition ? "one value" : "a different value";
```

In your case, though, you don't know that `tbtotalamount.Text` is blank until after you've done the `string.Format`, so you're better off leaving it with the `if`.

Comment: @kashif: You're welcome, glad that helped. (BTW, I don't see what all the fuss was about with the question. I voted to reopen, fwiw.)

Comment: with your above mentioned example I got that it is useless to use ? operator and leaving it with if is better... further more I got the main point i.e how and when ? operator is used. that is how it helped me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Here's how:

```
string test = string.Format("{0:n2}", dtl.Compute("sum(NetPay)", ""));
tbttotalamount.Text = test.length == 0 ? "0" : test;
```

Sorry to see so many downvotes, I'm not familiar with the ? (ternary) operator for a very long time either. I think it is very handy.

To the left of it is your test expression, it should be a boolean after evaluation. To the right is what the operator returns: if true, it will return the value to the left of the `:`. If false, the value to the right. Note that the whole expression returns something, and the compiler needs you to do something with it. You can't use the ternary operation to replace if-else statements that call functions whose return type is `void`.

What I mean to say is that a lot of people who've never used it before (like me) seem to think this is a **pure** if-else replacement, which it is **not**.

Comment: I was dreading the downvoting for this quesion. any ways thanks alot

Comment: This doesn't compile as `0` in an `int` literal and `test` is a `string` variable.

Comment: Will `0` be automatically converted to string? Didn't program on c# for a while, so not sure

Comment: I don't think the 2nd line even compiles.

Comment: dtl is the datatable. when I have no row I Get nothing. thus I have to put 0 in tbtotalamount.Text using if condition

Comment: @HenkHolterman before the edit it didn't.

Comment: If the real condition you're testing for is `dtl.Compute` returning null, why not use that? `var sum = dtl.Compute("sum(NetPay)", string.Empty); tbttotalamount.Text = (sum != null) ? string.Format("{0:n2}", sum) : "0";` Now that is something I'd probably write using the ternary operator in the first place - or you can use the null-coalescing operator too `(sum ?? 0)`